# Does adding values to a variable in printf() change the overall value of x?

Tags: c

```
int main() {
    x=5;
    printf("%d",x+3);
}
```

`x` could be either `5` or `8` after this example (I know that the output on the screen would be 8.)

Comment: `x` is `5` after the printf ... `printf("%d", x += 3);` would print `8` and change `x` to `8`.

Comment: You are not adding to x, you are adding x and 3. x will remain unchanged.

Comment: printf("%d", x++); would print the value of x then increment it. printf("%d", ++x); would first increment x then print it.

Comment: Why not test the idea yourself? Add `printf("\n%d", x);` after the first printf statement.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't add `printf("\n%d",x);` on the next line and find out yourself! Must. Ask. Internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value at the address of *x* remains unchanged in this example. Inside the *printf*, we first get the value at the address of *x* and then add it to 3 and output it to the screen.
This is why we use statements like *x=x+3* to change the value.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing doesn't exist. What's best to do is to perform the operation outside of the `printf()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    x += 3; // x = x + 3
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

According to [Tomo Ceferin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12917919/tomo-ceferin), `x` won't change because of the language's logic.

This works in C99. Not sure if any other version does.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x += 3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program does not compile because there is no definition for `x`.

You should also include `<stdio.h>` to declare `printf` properly.

The statement `printf("%d", x + 3);` does produce `8` on standard output, but it does not modify the variable `x`, assuming `x` is defined as `int x;` somewhere.

You could modify `x` inside the call to `printf`: this has always been supported by the C language, although it is considered confusing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x += 3);  // prints 8 with a side effect
    // x now has a value of 8
    printf("%d\n", x);       // prints 8 again
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of x remains the same, because you do not change it at all. Also, you should take into account to declare what type of data is your variable.
For example:

```
int main(){
int x = 5; //this is the variable x, declared as an integer. Its value is 5.
printf("%d", x + 3) //here you print an integer variable which has the value of (x+3),    
                  //(5 + 3 = 8), to be more precise. (this instruction has nothing to 
                 //do with the value of x, because you're not changing x in any way.)
```

}

So you will get on the screen the value of 8.
Hope it helped.